# How do I solve 1D diffusion equation on semi infinite line with nonhomogeneous boundary condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve a problem where a laser is heating the end of a semi-infinite line. Calculate the time dependence of temperature. Initial temperature is $0$.

As far as I understand we have the following problem:

$u_t-Du_{xx}=Q$ (where Q is the constant heat flux from the laser at $x=0$), on a semi infinite $1$D domain ($x\geq 0$).

B.C.: $u_x(x=0,t)=q$, which is a nonhomogeneous (non-zero) Neumann boundary at $x=0$ with constant value $q$.

I.C.: $u(x,t=0)=0$.

Question:

1. Am I missing a boundary condition? Can I also assume $u(x\to\infty,t)=0$?
2. My current idea is that I need to change my nonhomogeneous B.C. to homogeneous and then get a solution in form of $v = w + u$, where one is a solution to a homogeneous problem and the other fits the boundary conditions. Is this correct?
3. A more general approach would be finding the Greens function for this case. How would I find the correct Greens function and how do I then derive the correct integral expression for the solution $u(x,t)$? My idea for this was to use reflection and put the source at $x=0$ but I'm running into problems there because of the non zero Neumann boundary and also all other cases we have done had the source at some $x>0$, so that made logical sense how to mirror the functions. Having the source at $x=0$ doesn't make intuitive sense to me for solving with reflection.

Any ideas are welcome.